# UIView sliding upward direction automatically after removing the finger from the phone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

[image]

This is the screen I am working on currently. As you can see below side an UIView where I have used label and four buttons. And below that I have used table view to show menu. I have used SwipeGesture in order to slide the view up and down. What I want now whenever I touch the background image the UIView slides down completely and when I remove my finger
 from the screen the UIView automatically bounce up to the same position as shown in the image. Can anyone help me out??

This is my code I have worked so far-

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerUp:)];
[gestureRecognizerUp setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
[self.subview addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerUp];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandleDown:)];
[gestureRecognizerDown setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
[self.subview addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerDown];


- (void)swipeHandlerUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            CGPoint Position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+20);
            self.subview.frame = CGRectMake(Position.x , Position.y , self.subview.frame.size.width, self.subview.frame.size.height);
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)swipeHandleDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            CGPoint Position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x , self.view.frame.origin.y+430);
            self.subview.frame = CGRectMake(Position.x , Position.y , self.subview.frame.size.width, self.subview.frame.size.height);
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you use touchEnd method to recognize the finger release.

Comment: I don't know exactly. Will that work??

Comment: in your swipeHandlerUp method you have to move the frame up.So for Y axis, do something like this -  self.view.frame.origin.y -200. Then for swipeHandleDown method, -  self.view.frame.origin.y +200.

Comment: didn't work for me :( @Signare

Comment: showing any error ? @pri Your methods are executing ?.

Comment: no error but am not getting the desired reult. The view frame is swipping way up higher and how  the finger release will work???

Comment: i am using this code and its working perfect for me. [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:TRUE];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -200., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118177/discussion-between-signare-and-pri).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

And make sure to deselect all the three gesture behaviours like for both your swipeGestures.

```
Your_Swipe_gesture_Object.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
Your_Swipe_gesture_Object.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
Your_Swipe_gesture_Object.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            CGPoint Position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+20);
            self.subview.frame = CGRectMake(Position.x , Position.y , self.subview.frame.size.width, self.subview.frame.size.height);
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            CGPoint Position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x , self.view.frame.origin.y+430);
            self.subview.frame = CGRectMake(Position.x , Position.y , self.subview.frame.size.width, self.subview.frame.size.height);
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];
}
```

Comment: sorry saurabh it isn't the subview has to come completely down by dragging the view. And when the finger is released it should come up automatically

Comment: when you drag the finger the view.. you want to view show?

Comment: i don't get it what you saying.

Comment: there isn't a way to send videos in here? That way i could show what exactly i want

Comment: @pri What's the main problem in my code? Working fine in my side.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your code sir...but the subview shouldn't come upward by tapping but it should come up as i drag down the subview.

Comment: @pri can you give any other screenshot?